# How to determine fsk_deviation_hz?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

Using gnuradio how can I determine fsk_deviation_hz?
I'm new on rf analisys and I can't find how to retrieve that value starting from the signal... What i have to look?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not a programming question. Also, the frequency deviation in FSK is really not a complicated topic if you understand the basics of FSK, so please get a digital communications entry-level textbook and read up on FSK.

Comment: Maybe question was not clear... I know what fsk deviation is, I would like to know if there's a smart way to evaluate that using gnuradio (maybe an existent or 3rd party block).. Having to check many samples i'm trying to automatize that... Thanks anyway

Comment: You need to build a frequency estimator. But then, you probably wouldn't need to explicitly have the FSK deviation, because the freq estimator could already serve as demod.

Comment: That is, given you need an online deviation estimate. Usually, you just look at a spectrum estimate offline and infer from that manually.